# Is it possible to optimize hyperparameters for optional sklearn pipeline steps?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I tried to construct a pipeline that has some optional steps. However,  I would like to optimize hyperparameters for those steps as I want to get the best option between not using them and using them with different configurations (in my case SelectFromModel - sfm).

```
clf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 1)
stdscl = StandardScaler()
sfm = SelectFromModel(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1))

p_grid_lr = {"clf__max_depth": [10, 50, 100, None],
             "clf__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 800],
             "clf__max_features":[0.1, 0.5, 1.0,'sqrt','log2'],
             "sfm": ['passthrough', sfm],
             "sfm__max_depth": [10, 50, 100, None],
             "sfm__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 800],
             "sfm__max_features":[0.1, 0.5, 1.0,'sqrt','log2'],
            }

pipeline=Pipeline([
                 ('scl',stdscl),
                 ('sfm',sfm),
                 ('clf',clf)
                  ])

gs_clf = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipeline, param_grid = p_grid_lr, cv =KFold(shuffle = True, n_splits = 5, random_state=1),scoring = 'r2', n_jobs =- 1)
gs_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf = gs_clf.best_estimator_
```

The error that I get is 'string' object has no attribute 'set_params' which is understandable. Is there a way to specify which combinations should be tried together, in my case only 'passthrough' by itself and sfm with different hyperparameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by @Robin, you might define `p_grid_lr` as a list of dictionaries. Indeed, here is what the [docs of `GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) states at this proposal:

> param_grid: ***dict*** or ***list of dictionaries***

> Dictionary with parameters names (str) as keys and lists of parameter settings to try as values, ***or a list of such dictionaries, in which case the grids spanned by each dictionary in the list are explored***. This enables searching over any sequence of parameter settings.

```
p_grid_lr = [
    {
        "clf__max_depth": [10, 50, 100, None],
        "clf__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 800],
        "clf__max_features": [0.1, 0.5, 1.0,'sqrt','log2'],
        "sfm__estimator__max_depth": [10, 50, 100, None],
        "sfm__estimator__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 800],
        "sfm__estimator__max_features": [0.1, 0.5, 1.0,'sqrt','log2'],
    },
    {
        "clf__max_depth": [10, 50, 100, None],
        "clf__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 800],
        "clf__max_features": [0.1, 0.5, 1.0,'sqrt','log2'],
        "sfm": ['passthrough'],
    }
]
```

A less scalable alternative (for your case) might be the following

```
p_grid_lr_ = {
    "clf__max_depth": [10, 50, 100, None],
    "clf__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 800],
    "clf__max_features": [0.1, 0.5, 1.0,'sqrt','log2'],
    "sfm": ['passthrough', 
            SelectFromModel(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1, max_depth=10, n_estimators=10, max_features=0.1)),
            SelectFromModel(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1, max_depth=10, n_estimators=50, max_features=0.1)),
            ...]
}
```

specifying all of the possible combinations for your parameters.

Moreover, be aware that to access parameters `max_depth`, `n_estimators` and `max_features` from the `RandomForestRegressor` estimator within `SelectFromModel` you should type parameters as

```
"sfm__estimator__max_depth": [10, 50, 100, None],
"sfm__estimator__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 800],
"sfm__estimator__max_features": [0.1, 0.5, 1.0,'sqrt','log2']
```

rather than as

```
"sfm__max_depth": [10, 50, 100, None],
"sfm__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 800],
"sfm__max_features": [0.1, 0.5, 1.0,'sqrt','log2']
```

because these parameters are from the estimator itself (`max_features` in principle might also be a parameter from `SelectFromModel`, but in such a case it may only attain integer values as from [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html)).

In general you can access all the parameters to be possibly optimized via `pipeline.get_params().keys()` (`estimator.get_params().keys()` in general).

Eventually, here's a nice reading from the [user guide for Pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#nested-parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#exhaustive-grid-search) example you could just make a **list of dictionaries**. One containing `sfm` and its related parameters and the other one not using `"passthrough"`.